# Error in web ui hadoop related to webhdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I am using a single-node hadoop version release-3.3.1-RC3. In web ui hadoop under utilities -> browse the file system it is possible to view the contents of the file (beginning and end) directly in the browser. But instead I get the error `Couldn't preview the file. NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://desktop-ht79hb0.:9864/webhdfs/v1/user/lemit/output/part-r-00000?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=localhost:9000&length=32768&offset=0&_=1674670084685'.` , but with `hdfs dfs` in the console I can view the contents of the file.

What I tried: followed the link to the error (didn't help), changed the port (didn't help), changed the /etc/hosts file (didn't help)
What I expected: the ability to view the file using webhdfs in a browser

Comment: Your hostname has a period? `desktop-ht79hb0.`? Can you remove that?

Comment: Where can you change the hostname in webhdfs and remove the "."? Or do you suggest to just try it in the browser first?

Comment: That's an OS property. Has nothing to do with Hadoop or WebHDFS, which simply use the same setting. You could also try opening http://127.0.0.1:9864

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `/etc/hosts` file
2. Change `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
3. Change `hdfs-site.xml`, add the property:

   ```xml
   <property>
       <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
       <value>true</value>
   </property>
   ```